# jQuery SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Tags: jquery

New to jQuery and I want to create an external js file that when a button is click it shows an alert message.

This is what I have tried:

```
(function($){
    events: function(){
        $('#myModal').bind('click', function(e){
            alert("test");
        });
    }
})(jQuery,window,document);
```

I get an error:

> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

What I'm I doing wrong and is this the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're aiming for, but what you've got is a labelled function declaration with no identifier (hence the syntax error).

If all you need to do is bind an event handler, why do you need that function at all? Is this what you were aiming for?

```
(function($){
    $('#myModal').bind('click', function(e){
        alert("test");
    });
})(jQuery,window,document);
```

Alternatively, you may have intended `events` to be the key of an object:

```
(function($){
    var someObj = {
        events: function () {
            $('#myModal').bind('click', function(e){
                alert("test");
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery,window,document);
```

But it's hard to tell without knowing what you actually want to acheive.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `events` a key in an object:

```
(function($){
    var o = {
        events: function(){
            $('#myModal').bind('click', function(e){
                alert("test");
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery,window,document);
```

Or a named function:

```
(function($){
    function events() {
        $('#myModal').bind('click', function(e){
            alert("test");
        });
    }
})(jQuery,window,document);
```

Or get rid of the `function` stuff altogether:

```
(function($){
    $('#myModal').bind('click', function(e){
        alert("test");
    });
})(jQuery,window,document);
```

Without knowing what `events:` was for, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the event as follows

```
  (function($){
    $('#myModal').bind('click', function(e){
        alert("test");
    });
})(jQuery,window,document);

or

$('#myModal').click( function(e){
        alert("test");
    });
```